# How to find which tab page (TabControl) is on

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

What is the easyest way to find which tab is on. I want to show some data when i click on tabpage2 or some other tabpage. I did it like this but is not good solution:

```
private int findTabPage { get; set; }
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1)
            findTabPage = 1;
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage2)
            findTabPage = 2;
    }
```

and for displaying data:

```
 if (findTabPage == 1)
     { some code here }
 if (findTabPage == 2)
     { some code here }
```

Is there any other solution for example like this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
```

This will give you selected tab index which will start from 0 and go till 1 less then the total count of your tabs

Use it like this

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
             { some code here }
             break;
        case 1:
             { some code here }
             break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Before edit and this solution are acceptable to me, thanks for reply

Answer (score 4):

This is a much better approach.

```
private int CurrentTabPage { get; set; }
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentTabPage = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

In this way every time the tabindex is changed, our required CurrentTabPage would automatically updated.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer getting a string to identify the selected tabPage instead of its index:

```
int currentTab = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
string tabText = tabControl1.TabPages[currentTab].Text;
```

That will give the text on which you click when selecting the tabPage.

```
int currentTab = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
string tabName = tabControl1.TabPages[currentTab].Name;
```

And that will give you the name of the tabPage.

You can chose the Name programmatically or in the object properties, it's mandatory to have one different to identify each tabPage.
On the contrary, the Text field is not, and several different tabs can have the same text, you have to be careful with that.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use [`tabControl1.SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex.aspx):

```
if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    { some code here }
if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    { some code here }
```